# Angular 4 form validation: setting ng-dirty does not work in IE 11

Tags: angular

My templete HTML as follows:

```
<input formControlName="schduleName" 
        type="text"
        id="name"
        [style.width.%]="89.5"
         [class.ng-dirty]="!newSchdule.controls.schduleName.untouched || 
newSchdule.controls.schduleName.valid"/>
```

TS code as follows:

```
this.newSchdule = this.formBuilder.group({
        schduleName: ['', Validators.required],
        scheduleId: [this.defaultId, Validators.required],
        scheduleCreator: [this.defaultCreator, Validators.required],
        scheduleCreateTime: [this.defaultCreateTime, Validators.required]
    });
```

' [class.ng-dirty]' is work in chrome ,however does not work in IE 11. How to fix it? Anybody can help me? I am confused.

Comment: Did you check https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

Comment: What should I import Polyfills.ts to fix this problem?

Comment: classList right?

Comment: I have checked , however , it  is does not works .

Comment: The class binding itself should work in IE11. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jpfxhm). The problem may be with `ng-dirty`, or with the `untouched` or `valid` flags.

Comment: I can not open https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jpfxhm in IE 11.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I checked, ur right.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I find the problem is with untouched and valid. It's means that the code newSchdule.controls.schduleName.untouched is not work for IE11. I used newSchdule.get('passwordInfo.passwordConfirm').untouched before , however, when I use ng build -prod , it will console erro ,therefore, I use newSchdule.controls.schduleName.untouched now.  Have another method can do this?

Comment: Did you try `touched` instead of `!untouched`?

Comment: @ConnorsFan It's doesn't works.

Comment: According to [this other stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-uys6wg), `untouched` seems to work in IE11 also. :-)

Comment: @ConnorsFan It's weird. This is my TS code:this.newSchdule = this.formBuilder.group({
            schduleName: ['', Validators.required],
            scheduleId: [this.defaultId, Validators.required],
            scheduleCreator: [this.defaultCreator, Validators.required],
            scheduleCreateTime: [this.defaultCreateTime, Validators.required]
        });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am under the impression that by trying to set `ng-dirty` in your code, you are competing with Angular who tries to [manage it by himself](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#control-status-css-classes). If you want some custom formatting for the condition `!untouched && valid`, you could apply your own class name (e.g. `my-dirty`):

```
<input 
    id="name" 
    type="text" 
    formControlName="username" 
    class="form-control" 
    [class.my-dirty]="isDirty" />
```

I defined `isDirty` in the component class, for readability:

```
get isDirty(): boolean {
  return !this.form.controls.username.untouched && this.form.controls.username.valid;
}
```

The CSS file could contain style attributes for `ng-dirty` and for `my-dirty`:

```
input.my-dirty {
  background-color: lime;
}

input:not(.my-dirty) {
  background-color: orange;
}

input.ng-dirty {
  border: solid 4px red;
}
```

Use [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-uys6wg) to test the code in IE11 and in other browsers. You can see that `ng-dirty` is managed by Angular, while `my-dirty` is applied according to our condition `!untouched && valid`.